# Cookies set by php lost after browser closes, but those set by Javascript work fine

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am sure that the cookies were set using the following code:

PHP

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*365*20;
setcookie("user_id_2", $_SESSION['user_id'], $expire,'/');
```

Javascript

```
createCookie("done", "is_done", 36500);
```

Comment: What's in the `Set-Cookie` header for php? Btw, there is no built-in `createCookie` function in JS so without actual implementation the call is not helpful.